# Blurry Purple horizontal line across pics when scanning on v370

Tags: scanning

I have this thick blurry purple lines across my pictures when scanning on a brand new v370 scanner. Any idea where it's coming from? I've cleaned the scanner glass thoroughly and the negatives are clean[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

- The bar could be due to an [optical interference pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference), where a slightly-curved glossy photo touches the glass along a line. Test this by scanning a flat or matte surface, e.g. a plain piece of white paper.
- It could be the result of the scan-head getting stuck for a second and them jumping when it passes by the obstruction. The issue might go away if the obstruction is something like congealed lubricant or a speck of dust. Try repeated scans to see if the issue disappears.

If neither help, return the new scanner for a refund or another of the same model.

Comment: Agree with returning the scanner, but would try a different model.

Comment: @xiota depends on seller and jurisdiction, it may be only possible to get the same model as replacement. Also, this flaw is not a common issue with all v370, just this one, so changing model wouldn't really solve anything per se, would it?

Comment: If it's a curved negative, what would you suggest I do to straighten them out?

Comment: Just keep it from contacting the glass -- a fraction of a millimeter is sufficient. Supporting the edges with a paper mask would do.